# Syntax for passing a return value from one function to another with ProcessingJS?

Tags: java, function, variables, parameter-passing, processing

With ProcessingJS, I have a function that determines a number that I would like to give to another function:

```
int number;
int theNumbers() {
  // calculations for number

  int number = 10; // sample number
  return number;
}

void mousePressed() {
  // calculations for aLongNumber

  // pass theNumbers() number value
  theNumbers();
  long numberLong = aLongNumber + (number * aLongNumber);
}
```

For some reason, right now `numberLong = aLongNumber` and doesn't add (number * aLongNumber) because number has yet to pass to mousePressed() after calling theNumbers();

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @Beginner why doesn't number pass from theNumbers(); to numberLong in mousePressed() ?

Comment: Well I did not understand your question again (Sorry for that), but you may want to initialize number in the start as 'int number = 0; ' and change 'theNumbers()' call in mousePressed() method to 'number = theNumbers(); '  and see if this works for you. And yeah, you have initialized number twice. So remove 'int' from theNumbers() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and see if you get the required results:

```
int number = 0;
int theNumbers() {

number = 10; // sample number
return number;
}

void mousePressed() {
number = theNumbers();
long numberLong = aLongNumber + (number * aLongNumber);
}
```